# Derivation, zero-affixation verb tenses

Tags: morphology, derivation

I'm working on a paper about derivation, denominalization, zero-affixation and so on and have the following question:
If a verb derives from a noun and it used in a past tense, for example boycott - to boycott - boycotted does boycotted still belong to the zero-affixation?

Comment: [This may help](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf). It's a class handout summarizing the terms.

Answer (score 4):

“Boycotted” has no *derivational* affixes, so it belongs to *zero derivation* aka [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)). The affix *-ed* is an *inflectional* affix, so you cannot generally say “boycotted” is an example of zero affixation, it does have an affix.

It all depends on what you are talking about. If it goes *only* about derivation mechanisms, then “boycotted” is an example of a zero-affixation derivation, since it is not anything like **boycott**ize**d* or **boycott**ifi**ed*, no derivational affixes are present.

It looks like this point is exactly what you have to come up with in your paper, you have to just find a way of wording to set apart the derivational and inflectional affixes, to make it clear when you write about the former and when about the latter or both together.

Comment: Thank you so much!
That's what I was thinking but then I started doubting my 'conclusion'.
So, just to clarify, if I have the noun bridge, I can derive the verb to bridge from it but I can only derive bridged and not bridging from it because the stem of the word changed, right? (Sorry, I couldn't come up with a better example.)

Comment: You wrote an answer to your own question, it should have been a commentary to my answer. Anyhow. I see no substantial difference between “bridged” and “bridging”, both are just forms of the verb “to bridge”.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me out. I have another question... Even though the "e" in bridge is deleted in "bridging", it still is a derivation? I thought that wouldn't be the case. Same with skate/skating or spice/spicing.

Comment: The “e” is just a letter, a silent one, a spelling convention, no sound is dropped when “-ing” is added, cf. “ski” [ski:] - “skiing” [ˈski:.ɪŋ], it is still zero derivation.